# Asp.Net MVC - dynamically altering ActionLink via jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have used jQuery to display info for a record depending on some user selections. I need to add a button or a link that will take them to an Edit view, but don't know the best way to achieve this. The ID for the navigation will change as they browse the data.

Can I dynamically alter the ActionLink using jQuery?

**More info**
Users make a selection from list boxes, then I go and get the appropriate data via a $.getJSON call. Information is then displayed in a summary box with the option to edit the data.
So the fetch looks like this

```
$.getJSON("/Result/FetchState", { metricId: metId, calendarId: calId }, function (data) {
              $('#Info1').val(data.ResultId);
              $('#Info3').val(data.Headline);
              if (data.AllowEdit) { $('#btnEdit').attr('disabled', false); } else { $('#btnEdit').attr('disabled', true); }
              $('#editlink').val(data.ResultId);
          });
```

I now need to be able to navigate to a View (/Result/Edit/{id}) where {id} is the ResultId from the FetchState call.

Comment: You can use jQuery to alter the href of the link that ActionLink has generated yes. This might be a bit brittle if the path to the application or the view changes in future. My gut feeling is to pass an edit link to the view rather than try and generate one. Perhaps you could hide it by default and just use jQuery to display it.

Comment: A bit more detail (and some code) would help give you a better answer.

Comment: Yeah, I don't like the idea of altering the href directly. All I really need to do is inject an Id into the Url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `<form>` containing a hidden field and a submit button. When the user performs some selection you would set the value of the hidden field to this new selection:

```
$('#SomeHiddenField').val('some new value');
```

Then when the user submits the button this will redirect to the new action passing along the value of the hidden field.